What is the meaning of 'in the note'?
It's from Edith Wharton's "Afterward", a short story published in 1910.
I can't figure out the real meaning of 'in the note' in the paragraph below.

But when she dipped into the damp heat of the greenhouses, among the spiced scents and waxy pinks and reds of old-fashioned exotics,
— even the flora of Lyng was in the note!—she learned that the great man had not arrived, and the day being too rare to waste in an artificial atmosphere, she came out again and paced slowly along the springy turf of the bowling-green to the gardens behind the house. At their farther end rose a grass terrace, commanding, over the fish-pond and the yew hedges, a view of the long house-front, with its twisted chimney-stacks and the blue shadows of its roof angles, all drenched in the pale gold moisture of the air.


It's not an easy sentence to decode, but I suspect the answer lies in this definition of "note" from the Cambridge dictionary:

an emotion or a way of expressing something:
-There was a note of caution in her letter.
-His speech struck just the right note.
-The meeting ended on an optimistic note.

The emotion(s) in question here are highlighted earlier in the paragraph that contains the sentence in question:

The task involved on such charmed winter days almost as much delighted loitering about the different quarters of her demesne as if spring were already at work on shrubs and borders. There were such inexhaustible possibilities still before her, such opportunities to bring out the latent graces of the old place, without a single irreverent touch of alteration, that the winter months were all too short to plan what spring and autumn executed. And her recovered sense of safety gave, on this particular morning, a peculiar zest to her progress through the sweet, still place.

In other words, Mary is going about her morning's work with a sense of engagement and hope: she is enjoying herself, pottering about the old house and looking for objects of delight, the "latent graces" of the house that can be enjoyed with little or no alterations.
In this sense, the "spiced scents" and "waxy pinks and reds" of the house's "flora" - Lyng is the name of the property - that she encounters in the greenhouse chime with her emotional sense of engagement and anticipation. They are things to be savoured and enjoyed on an otherwise dull winter's day, and are thus in the "note" of her emotional state.

This term comes from perfuming.  A note is part of a scent.  These can be analyzed in terms of when they are smelled, but in this context, it means only that she can smell "flora of Lyng" in the room.
Also in this context, it carries the suggestion that she smelled but did not see it

This answer could be improved by adding some evidence that the phrase was used in this sense.

I'm not convinced by this: why would a comment on a "note" of perfume follow directly on from the mention of the colour of the flowers?

@MattThrower  Also "spiced scent"

Yes, but that prefixes the colour, and the "note" is after the colours, so if that's the reference you expect the "note" to be about colour, not the scents. Also, the "flora of Lyng" is what's giving off the scent so why would it also be "in" that scent?

@MattThrower I read it as saying that in addition to the other plants, the flora of Lyng was also present in the scent. Exactly what is meant by flora of Lyng would require reading the original story, but since it's capitalized, my guess is it refers to the native flora found in a specific location called Lyng, such as the parish of that name in England.

@barbecue I've read the story. Lyng is the name of the house where it is set. So the "Flora of Lyng" is the plants in the house's greenhouse, which has already been described as emitting the scent.

@MattThrower I'm not convinced the note refers to color rather than scent. That's not a common usage of the word note. Also, having now read the story, the scene is a hothouse, not an outdoor area. Combined with the spiced scent, I feel the character is remarking that in addition to the smells of the various hothouse plants, she also smells the scent of the native flora in the immediate area.

@barbecue I'm not saying it refers to colour - in fact that's a big part of my point. I'm saying that if the "note" reference is related to the scent in the immediately preceding statements, it makes no sense that the colours come after the smells because there is no link between "note" and "colour".

@MattThrower The link is they're in the same sentence. The "in the note" part is intended to be a sudden interjection added as an aside. This is clear from the use of  em dashes and an exclamation mark. The obvious interpretation is that the speaker enters the hothouse, and is immediately presented with sensory input including both colors and smells. She specifically interjects the "flora of Lyng" as a surprising element, she didn't expect that to be present in the hothouse, which is a closed environment. If "flora of Lyng" means the plants in the hothouse, it would be redundant.

Mary is expecting an engineer who will look at the pipework in the greenhouse, and refers to that person as "an authority from Dorchester":

There was something wrong about the piping of the hot-house, and she was expecting an authority from Dorchester, (…).

The only way to contact the engineer was by writing, i.e. by sending a letter or "note". This is why the man is referred to again in the next part of the sentence (emphasis mine):

But when she dipped into the damp heat of the greenhouses, among the spiced scents and waxy pinks and reds of old-fashioned exotics—even the flora of Lyng was in the note!—she learned that the great man had not arrived, (…).

The "flora of Lyng" are the plants in the greenhouse, which depend on the greenhouse's pipework and are therefore mentioned in the note.

Was the only way by sending a letter? No telephones? (I don't know - I've not read the story - I just ask for information).

@ClaraDíazSanchez There was no telephone. (The fact that the house missed "modern" comfort was one of the reasons why the Boynes bought Lyng.) And "notes" and other types of written communication play an important role in the story.

I'm skeptical that a note written to a technician about a malfunctioning boiler would focus on the flora and scents.

@barbecue The note doesn't focus on the flora, it just mentions it. The plants in the greenhouse are mentioned because the guy is coming to check the plumbing there.
